# The granularity between LineChart and CandleStickChart is different

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a demand,the CandleStickChart and the LineChart is showing on the same table,but i find a question, [rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpanF.png) ,
the YAxis granularity between LineChart and CandleStickChart is different

Layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.my.myapplication1.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CandleStickChart
        android:id="@+id/chart1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/linechart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

the code setting YAxis of LineChart and CandleStickChart :

```
YAxis axisLeft = linechart.getAxisLeft();
axisLeft.setAxisMinimum(0);
axisLeft.setGranularity(1);
axisLeft.setLabelCount(7, false);
axisLeft.setDrawGridLines(false);
axisLeft.setDrawAxisLine(false);

YAxis leftAxis = candleChart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
leftAxis.setGranularity(1);
leftAxis.setLabelCount(7, false);
leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
leftAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
```

although i set the granularity ,it's not work. How can i do to let the granularity of them be the same?Anyone help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.my.myapplication1.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CandleStickChart
        android:id="@+id/chart1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
       android:id="@+id/linechart"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Use:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.my.myapplication1.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart
        android:id="@+id/chart1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then look combined chart example here in link below:

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java

Comment: WOW, Great, Thank you helped me a lot.